# Слово "кукуруза"

Tags: этимология

На всех языках она называется маис (a mais) и только по-русски - кукуруза. Почему? Откуда взялось это слово?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В русском языке слово КУКУРУЗА появилось в I половине XIX века и пришло оно откуда-то с юга. Предположение о славянском происхождении и родстве с болг. *кукуряк* "чемерица", словен. *kukurjav*, *kukurjast* "курчавый" не устраняет трудностей словообразования (-dz-). Некоторые исследователи возводили это слово к турецкому kokoroz - 'стебель кукурузы' (при том, что 'кукуруза' - misir). Но родиной кукурузы является не Турция, а Центральная и Южная Америка. В Европу же кукурузу завезли испанцы. Не исключено, что в турецком слово kokoroz тоже заимствованное, возможно даже из южнославянских языков (см. указанные выше словенсоке и болгарское соответствия). У Фасмера упоминается и такая версия: "Заслуживает внимания гипотеза о происхождении из kukuru -- подзывание домашней птицы при кормлении зернами кукурузы". (Использованы данные словарей П.Я. Черных и М.Фасмера).

Answer (score 0):

*Кукуру́за **са́харная***, также *маис* - единственный культурный представитель рода кукуруза(википедия) сахарная: по литовски - cukrus, по латышски - cukurs

Как вариант происхождения слова от слова ***сахарный.***

Comment: Ерунда. К Задорнову.

Comment: Cucurbita melo реро, это для справки, тоже к Задорнову?

Answer (score -1):

Сторонники версии "сахарная", по-видимому, наиболее близки к истине.

В свое время слово "кукуруза" было напрямую позаимствовано у венгров западными украинцами (в рамках соседско-деловых сношений между Австро-Венгерской империей  и Российской державой у ее западных границ), от слова "kukorica" (субстантивизированного прилагательного в значении "сладкая", "сахаристая"). Венгры предпочли общеевропейскому maiz свой "домашний" синоним "кукурица" (сахаристая). Кстати, украинские журналисты теперь нередко называют ее поэтическим выражением "качаниста" (обрадающая початками).

Цепочка последовательности: "сukorica"(венг.) - "кукурудза"(укр.) - "кукуруза"(рус.). Чередование же согласных -с-, -z- у западных соседей со славянскими -ц-, -дз- и проч. - дело традиционно обычное и широко распространенное.

Проверочное слово "сахар": "сukor"(венг.), "цукор"(укр.),""cukier (польс.), "Zucker" (нем.), и иже с ними по всей доброй старушке Европе.

Comment: _Обрадающая початками_  — это какая: обладающая или обрастающая?